# Good architecture for drawing shapes

Tags: java, oop, drawing

For my software engineering object-oriented design class, we are tasked with implementing a simple "Paint" application that can draw simple things like Ellipses, Rectangles, Lines, Free-form curves, and Text.

I am really trying to go for the gold here, and come up with a really clean and elegant architecture, because we need to support things like printing, saving, and exporting to an image, and I want to be able to do so with minimal effort.

So far, I have three "tiers" of classes:

1. Shape classes: `Ellipse`, `Rectangle`, `Line`, `Textbox` and `Freeform`, all inheriting from my custom `Shape` class
2. Style classes, each of which implements `GraphicsModifier`, which allows the class to change the `Graphics2D` object

   - `StrokeStyle` describes how the shape's stroke should be drawn, with `Stroke` and `Paint` objects
   - `FillStyle` describes the fill , with a `Paint` object
   - `TextStyle` is basically a wrapper for AWT's font classes, allowing easy modification of font sizes, styles, and faces.
3. Drawing classes

Right now, I am stuck on how my drawing classes should be implemented.

My initial thoughts were to have something like

```
class DrawingObject {
    StrokeStyle stroke;
    FillStyle fill;
    TextStyle text;
    Shape shape;

    void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        //????
    }
}
```

The issue is that, if `shape` is a `Freeform`, I need to apply only `stroke` and loop through each point in the curve and draw it separately. If `shape` is a `Rectangle`, `Line`, or `Ellipse`, I need to apply only `stroke` and `fill`, and use `g.draw(Shape)`. If `shape` is a `Textbox`, I need to apply all three `stroke`, `fill`, and `text`, and use `g.drawString()`.

It occurred to me that this might be a good place to apply a Strategy pattern, switched on the subclass of `shape`:

```
if (shape instanceof Freeform) {
    strategy = new FreeformDrawer(shape);
} else if (shape instanceof Rectangle || ... ) {
    strategy = new NormalDrawer(shape);
} else if (shape instanceof Textbox) {
    strategy = new TextboxDrawer(shape);
}
strategy.draw(g);
```

(I guess I could use a little reflection magic to `switch` on the class name too, but that's beside the point)

But somehow this feels a little dirty.

**How would you tackle this problem? Am I going about this wrong? Is Strategy a good idea here?**

If it matters, I'm using Java and Swing to implement this, but in theory it should be applicable to any OO language/framework.

---

tl;dr:
Given a bunch of objects to be drawn in different ways, and styles that get applied to them in differing capacities, how would you draw them, using good object-oriented design?

Answer (score 1):

You're right - it does feel a little dirty :)

The reason is that if you were to really use the strategy pattern you would need to replace your existing subclasses. So there would be no Rectangle class anymore, there would just be a Shape with its strategy set to RectangleDrawer. Then there's no need for that ugly set of ifs, because there's no need to map anything.

In this case though, I don't think strategy would be your best option. Strategy is great for when you need to change behaviors dynamically, and I'm guessing in your program once a square is drawn it's never going to change to a circle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for an inheritance heirarchy, it's too flat.

You really want something like:

```
Drawable
+-Shape
| +-Rectangle
| +-etc.
+-FreeForm
+-etc.
```

Alternatively, keep the flat heirarchy, and use a virtual `render()` method. Render should just return a bitmap, and then your draw method can be something like:

```
void draw(Shape s) {
    graphics.Draw(s.render(), s.x, s.y);
}
```

You can then override `render` in each of your classes, so that Rectangle produces a solid-colour bitmap, Ellipse returns a bitmap that is transparent around the outside but solid-colour in an elliptical shape in the center, etc.

Community Wiki so that if anyone feels they have something to add, they can go right ahead and add it.

Comment: Well, I simplified my example a little. That's pretty much the hierarchy I have, except my top level is `Shape`, then `Rectangle`, `Ellipse`, `Line` all inherit from `RectangularShape`, which extends `Shape`. `Freeform` and `Textbox` directly extend `Shape`

Comment: Also, I wanted to keep my shapes only concerned with their own properties, not drawing themselves. If I do what you suggest, my shapes now "know" about bitmaps, which semantically, they should not.